# Using Numpy.rate to calculate annualised interest rate

Tags: python, numpy, quantitative-finance

I am exploring Numpy.rate function to determine the annualised interest rate in order to attain a future value within a defined time period.

For example:

- I have an initial saving of $10,000 to create an investment portfolio
- Every month I will contribute $500 to this portfolio
- At the end of 15 years, I hope to see my portfolio grow to $120,000 (with compounding effect)

Below is my code snippet in Python:

```
    import numpy as np

    initial_value = 10000.0

    monthly_payment = 500.0

    number_of_years = 15

    future_value = 120000.0

    np.rate(number_of_years, -monthly_payment*12, initial_value, future_value, when='end')

: 0.06583239141591554
```

Based on the output, does it mean the annualised return is 0.0658 * 100 = 6.58%?

Answer (score -1):

Yes. According to the documentation (which you can find [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.rate.html)), the `np.rate` function solves for `rate` in the formula `fv + pv*(1+rate)**nper + pmt*(1+rate*when)/rate * ((1+rate)**nper - 1) = 0`. Since you are providing the number of payments as annual period, `rate` is an annual percentage.